# Jquery update ckfinder form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckfinder

I'm trying to update an input field value `.ckfinder-input` via ck finders pop up image selector.
It all works fine until I try and assign the selected image URL to the input field `input.val() = fileUrl` and get the following error message:

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Could someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```js
$(".ckfinder-modal-button").on("click", function() {
  input = $(this).parent().find(".ckfinder-input");
  BrowseServer(input);
});

function BrowseServer(input) {
  var finder = new CKFinder();
  finder.selectActionData = input;
  finder.selectActionFunction = function(fileUrl, data) {
    input = data['selectActionData'];
    console.log(input); //returns Object[input.form-control.ckfinder-input property value = "" attribute value = "null"]
    console.log(fileUrl); //returns "/customer_images/header_images/home.jpg"
    input.val() = fileUrl; // ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side;
  }
  finder.resourceType = 'HeaderImages';
  finder.removePlugins = 'basket';
  finder.popup();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bootstrap-filestyle input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control ckfinder-input" name="ckfinder-input">
  <span class="group-span-filestyle input-group-btn ckfinder-modal-button" tabindex="0">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="icon-span-filestyle fa fa-cloud-upload"></span>
  </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably it's because your JavaScript is invalid. You cannot assign a value (`fileUrl`) to the output of function (`input.val()`) in:
`js
input.val() = 'abc';`

You should either:

a) if it is [DOM Input Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement):

`input.value = 'abc';`

b) if it's [jQuery wrapper for DOM Element](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

`input.val( 'abc' );`

Comment: Ahhh - thank you - I change to `input.val(fileUrl)` and it worked a treat.